# Seeking Linux window manager, programmable, mouse optional, drag and drop photos

Tags: linux, photos, window-manager, drag-and-drop

I've been using fvwm for over 20 years.  But it doesn't support drag and drop, and I would like to be able to drag and drop photos from some sort of photo viewer into Chrome.  I have no idea how drag and drop works on Linux, so I have some questions:

1. Do I need a new window manager, or is there some other trick I'm missing?
2. Do I also need a photo program that understands drag and drop?
3. If I need a new window manager, what can you recommend that

   - Is lightning fast
   - Has no required panels, taskbars, icons, or any other junk that uses up precious pixels (if I want a menu I know how to press buttons)
   - Allows me to program my own keyboard shortcuts for all actions
   - Allows me to control which keystrokes are intercepted by a window manager and which are delivered to windows
   - Does not require me to tile windows
   - Can support NxM "virtual desktops" like the FVWM Pager

---

**FOLLOWUP**: It turns out that fvwm *does* support drag and drop, at least between Nautilus and Shotwell.  So the problem I am experiencing may be a Chrome problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The window manager needs to support XDnD.
2. Yes, but almost all of them support it.
3. I used to use [wmii](http://wmii.suckless.org/). It's a tiler by default, but it fully supports floating windows. As for customizability – all events are handled by one large, editable script (rc/bash/ruby/python/anything).